# Error: Lcobucci\JWT\UnencryptedToken cannot implement Lcobucci\JWT\Token - it is not an interface

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, jwt

I have used [LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/tree/2.x)   to implement JWT-based authentication for my Symfony project. I have followed the steps given in a couple of guides and all of them are identical. Following is a one reference link https://symfony.com/bundles/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/current/index.html .

After following the given steps I get the following error when trying to get a token and this is coming for all routes which need authentication as well. Anything that I have done wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using a too old version of `lcobucci/jwt`

Update it.

```
composer require lcobucci/jwt:^4.0
```